# How do I fix this URL regexp to match URLs at the end of the string?

Tags: php, html, regex, string

I found this great URL matching `regexp` from another answer here that gets URL's in a string, but it only works if they are followed by spaces.

```
preg_replace('#(https?|ftp)://[^ ]+ #i', '', $s['Text']);
```

How would I modify this so that it will also match URL's that are at the very end of a string with nothing after them?

Comment: But then it matches everything that's typed after http:// and doesn't wait for a valid extension. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: A simple fix that won't make your regex reject invalid URLs better though is `preg_replace('#(https?|ftp)://[^\s\r\n]+(?:$|[\s\r\n])#i', '', $s['Text']);`. This will either match the end of the string or any whitespace. You might also want to look at http://regular-expressions.info tutorial or so, it will also explain non-capturing groups `(?:...)` and lookahead which may be helpful here.

Comment: Can you please link the answer where you've found that reference? And have you left a comment there that it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching with all kind of URLs the following code can help you:

```
<?php

$content = '<html>

<title>Random Website I am Crawling</title>

<body>

Click <a href="http://clicklink.com">here</a> for foobar

Another site is http://foobar.com';

$regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME
$regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass
$regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})"; // Host or IP
$regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port
$regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path
$regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query
$regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor


$matches = array(); //create array
$pattern = "/$regex/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches); 

print_r(array_values(array_unique($matches[0])));
echo "<br><br>";
echo implode("<br>", array_values(array_unique($matches[0])));


?>
```

Comment: Hey Adrian, I just noticed that this Regexp leaves off "9GorqroigqM" from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GorqroigqM - any suggestion on how to fix that? It seems to catch everything up to the =

Comment: Important: This regex won't accept new TLDs longer than 4 chars, local TLDs, non-standard names with underscores nor any Unicode/UTF-8 domain names (IDNs). Also, using the extended PCRE syntax might be better than concatenation (haven't tried though). Using a delimiter char not used in the regex also allows some escaping to be removed.

Comment: Thanks @Archimedix - is there a better one you recommend?

Comment: @MichaelF not strictly better because it will match non-URLs like `http://;@!?` as well but at least no false negatives (unrecognized valid URLs), and nearer to your regex, see my comment to your question.